# Load callback and show div jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
$('#mydiv').load('index.php #mydiv', function() {
    $('#mydiv').show();
});

<div id="mydiv" style="display: none;">
    Some text
</div>
```

"Some text" never displays with this code when I run the function, the div displays though. But if I remove display: none, everything displays when I run the function. This has never been a trouble for me before.

What´s wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to `load` a single element with `id` "myDiv" from "index.php", and place that loaded element inside an element with `id` "myDiv". Doing so will result in two elements on the page with the same ID, and that's not valid.

Try changing either the ID of the `div` that you load the content into, or the ID of the element that you are loading:

```
$('#mydiv2').load('index.php #mydiv', function() {
    $('#mydiv2').show();
});

<div id="mydiv2" style="display: none;">
    Some text
</div>
```

Comment: This is indeed the issue, an alternative solution to it (assuming all children were elements) would be changing the selector to `index.php #mydiv>*`.

Comment: @Daniel - It selects all direct children of `#mydiv`. Have a look through the jQuery selector docs for more info: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ and in particular http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Answer (score 0):

`display: none` means  visibility of the div is set to Hidden

The display property specifies if/how an element is displayed, and the visibility property specifies if an element should be visible or hidden.
[Difference between Display and visibility in css](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)

Comment: then you should use `visibility:hidden` insted of `display: none`

Comment: @Shebin - that's not going to help. The jQuery `show` method is correct in this case.